# Converting Hexadecimal to decimal won't return result

Tags: python

In a `.txt` file I have written a few hexadecimal numbers:

```
'3001','1018','1200'
```

These numbers must be converted into decimal form.

CODE:

```
indeks = {}
f = open("data.txt")
data = f.readlines()
for line in data:
    key, value = line.split(",")
    indeks[key.strip()] = value.strip()
f.close()
pass

for s in indeks:
    pass

def i():
    ser.write(chr(s))
    x=ser.read(4)
    z=struct.unpack("h", x)[0]
    i = int(z, 16)
    print i
```

The problem is that it won't print me `i`.

I write code with help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11826054/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-16-x0e-xa3-python) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006974/how-to-read-input-file-in-python) but still don't know where the problem is.

Comment: You never call `i`, which looks like overkill. Why not just use `int(value, 16)`?

Comment: You have both a function `i` and a variable `i` - that's not a great idea. Also, you code (`key, value = line.split(",")`) doesn't match the data you say is in the file (just the values).

Comment: You appear to be copying random lines from the other posts; try to *understand* what the code does before blindly copying stuff in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the contents of the file and then convert that to a number using `int` function, like this

```
with open("Input.txt") as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        data = line.rstrip().replace("'", "").split(",")
        print data
        print [int(number, 16) for number in data]
# [12289, 4120, 4608]
```

Here,

`in_file.read()` - will read the contents of the file

`rstrip()` - will remove the whitespace characters at the end of the string

`replace(",", "")` - will remove all the `'`

`split(",")` - will split the data based on `,`

At this point, the data will look like this

```
['3001', '1018', '1200']
```

Now we use `int` function to convert each item to a number and we pass the second argument `16` to make `int` treat the data as hexadecimal.

**Note:** We use `for line in file_object` construct, which is better than the `readlines`, because `readlines` will read the entire file and store it in the memory as a list, but `for` construct will read the next line only when asked for.